# How do I change my listview item value when I double click it?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, listview, events

So my application works and its doing fine, but I feel like im starting to clutter the app with new windows. 
What I am doing right now is, im populating my ListView with a list that I am getting from using the StreamReader class.
I am also using a class that I made that I bind all the data with.

And what happends when I double click a ListViewItem is that a new window opens with the property & the value already filled out and you can change it that way.
But what I want to do is to get rid of the new window that opens and just be able to change the value in the ListView when I double click.
What are my options and what would be the proper way of achieving this?

XAML

```
            </ListView.View>
            <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                    <EventSetter Event="PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" Handler="ListViewItem_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" />
                </Style>
            </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        </ListView>
```

CS

```
private void ListViewItem_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            if (sender is ListViewItem item && item.IsSelected)
            {
                var SelectedServerProperties = ((ServerProperties)lvServerProperties.SelectedItem);
                Properties.Settings.Default.ServerProperty = SelectedServerProperties.Property;
                Properties.Settings.Default.ServerPropertyValue = SelectedServerProperties.Value;

                PropertyChangerWindow pcw = new PropertyChangerWindow();
                pcw.Show();
            }
        }
```

PropertyWindow

```
public partial class PropertyChangerWindow : Window
    {
        public PropertyChangerWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            tbProperty.Text = Properties.Settings.Default.ServerProperty;
            tbValue.Text = Properties.Settings.Default.ServerPropertyValue;
        }

    }
```

ServerProperties Class

```
public class ServerProperties
{
    public string Property { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you replace the `ListView` with a `DataGrid`, you will be able to enter the edit mode of a cell by simply double-clicking on it:

```
<DataGrid>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Property" Binding="{Binding Property}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Value" Binding="{Binding Value}" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

The `DataGrid` provides this functionality out of the box.

Comment: Amazing! Quick question, is there a way to get rid of the vlue arrows that shows up? Do I need toe dit the template perchaps? https://i.imgur.com/iTIBIA4.gifv

Comment: Just set the CanUserSortColumns property of the DataGrid to false.

Comment: Ah so that's what it is! And if its not too much to ask, do you happen to know why I keep getting the EditItem is not allowed for this view when double click an item? Or should I post a new question about that?