# How do I add a datagrid to my tabitem to represent a lsitview

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I have a grid with a tabcontrol in it and it looks like this.[image]

And I would like to add a datagrid to one of my tabs so it looks like this inside my Server Settings tab
[image]

I cant use a listviewitem inside it because I cant doubleclick the rows to change the value with a listview. (spoken about that in this question)
[How do I change my listview item value when I double click it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46730829/how-do-i-change-my-listview-item-value-when-i-double-click-it)

So how do I add the gridview inside my tab?

XAML TabControl

```
<Grid>
    <TabControl>
        <TabItem Header="General">
            <Grid>
                <GroupBox Header="Settings" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="145" Margin="2,4,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="323" Style="{DynamicResource GroupBoxStyle1}"/>
                <CheckBox x:Name="cbThing" Content="Play Sound On Login" Click="cbThing_Checked" Margin="18,33,518,208"/>
                <CheckBox Content="Play Sound On Logout" Margin="18,52,548,196"/>
            </Grid>
        </TabItem>

        <TabItem Header="Server Settings"/>

        <TabItem Header="Details" />

    </TabControl>
</Grid>
```

XAML DataGrid

```
<Grid>
    <DataGrid Name="dgItems" Margin="0,0,0,35">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <!--<DataGridTextColumn Header="Property" Binding="{Binding Property}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Value" Binding="{Binding Value}" />-->
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>

</Grid>
```

I tried doing it like this

```
    <TabItem Header="Server Settings"/>
    <DataGrid Name="dgItems" Margin="0,0,0,35">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Property" Binding="{Binding Property}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Value" Binding="{Binding Value}" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

Which results in this..

[image]

Comment: What is the question? Are you asking how to edit a text file?

Comment: How do I add a datagrid to my tabitem to represent a lsitview. You see the second picture I added? I want to add a datagrid like that into my tabitem

Comment: What's the problem? You have XAML for a datagrid. You know how to copy and paste text. You know how to put content in a TabItem. What is your question?

Comment: The issue is that if i add the datagrid to the tabitem it looks like this https://i.imgur.com/uNdS0TM.png I'll update the question with that the xaml looks like

Comment: So put it inside the tabitem element. Not next to it. Inside it. You need an open tag `<TabItem>`, followed by content, followed by a close tag `</TabItem>`. You just have `<TabItem />`, a single tag that has no content. Look at the tab item that DOES have content. Do it like that one. If you do it differently and you get different results, what does that tell you? It tells you to do it the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your XML tags need to have their content inside them, not just kind of somewhere in the vicinity.

This tag has no close tag, so it can have no content.  See how it ends with `/>`? No close tag, no content.

```
<TabItem Header="Server Settings"/>
```

This one has content: The open tag ends with just `>`, and there is a matching close tag `</TabItem>`. Same for the `Grid` tag inside the `TabItem` tag. This is copied straight from your question. I see the same open/close tag pattern in your `DataGrid` XAML. Did you write this, or did somebody else?

```
<TabItem Header="General">
    <Grid>
        <GroupBox Header="Settings" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="145" Margin="2,4,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="323" Style="{DynamicResource GroupBoxStyle1}"/>
        <CheckBox x:Name="cbThing" Content="Play Sound On Login" Click="cbThing_Checked" Margin="18,33,518,208"/>
        <CheckBox Content="Play Sound On Logout" Margin="18,52,548,196"/>
    </Grid>
</TabItem>
```

So do it like this:

```
<TabItem Header="Server Settings">
    <DataGrid Name="dgItems" Margin="0,0,0,35">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Property" Binding="{Binding Property}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Value" Binding="{Binding Value}" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</TabItem>
```

Comment: Ahh! That's where I went wrong, I am still new to XAML, and I forgot that whats inbetween the opening &/ closing tag is what actually belongs tot hat element! Thanks!